# Simplify code with two variables?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I am not sure if I am asking this right, but basically i am trying to simplify my code so I don't have to write the same thing 5 times. 
I have included two samples below. You can see that the only thing that changes is the event.X and the ".ia-event-x".

```
// For title
if (event.title) {
    $(".ia-event-title").html(event.title);
     $(".ia-event-title").addClass('ia-populated');
}
else if (!event.title) {
    $(".ia-event-title").removeClass('ia-populated');
}

// For Description
if (event.description) {
    $(".ia-event-description").html(event.description);
     $(".ia-event-description").addClass('ia-populated');
}
else if (!event.description) {
    $(".ia-event-description").removeClass('ia-populated');
}
```

Comment: Yes, use a loop over an array of class names. Please try and show us your approach.

Comment: There's neither a loop nor an array here...

Comment: I mean, you could. But it looks like you already wrote the same thing twice so I don't see much of an advantage. You could also make a function and pass parameters to it, which would probably be a better approach.

Comment: I came up with this and it seems to work, anything glaringly wrong here? https://jsfiddle.net/82q9uL6d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function that I'm passing my parameters too as needed.

```
function createPopupContent(eventParameter, eventClass) {
  if (eventParameter) {
    $(eventClass).html(eventParameter);
    $(eventClass).addClass('ia-populated');
  }
  else if (!eventParameter) {
    $(eventClass).removeClass('ia-populated');
  }
}
```

Comment: There are no needs for `else if (!eventParameter) {`, a simple `else {` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward. Note: This is the shortest solution that assumes all data and DOM follow same pattern.

```
var array = ['title','description']
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
    var s = array[i];
    var obj = $(".ia-event-" + s);
    if (event[s]) 
        obj.html(event[s]).addClass('ia-populated');
    else 
        obj.removeClass('ia-populated');
}
```

Comment: this would work, except that I found that my start time has a different format. thanks for your help though!